# Docker volume not working with Nginx

Tags: nginx, docker

I've created a simple Docker container with Nginx inside and for some reason, it won't access the `www` volume data from the host.

Here is the command I used:

```
docker run \
    -d \
    -p 8080:80 \
    --name nginx \
    --restart always \
    -v /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro \
    -v /var/www:/usr/share/nginx/html \
    -v /home/myuser/myvhost.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myvhost.conf:ro \
    -v /var/log/nginx:/var/log/nginx \
    nginx:1.9.4;
```

All the volumes are correctly mounted (I checked with `docker inspect`) but when go on the website I get a 404 and the Nginx `error.log` on the host says:

```
"/var/www/docker/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory)
```

It's surprising because this path is definitely correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx is looking for content in `/var/www`, and you don't appear to be mounting anything on `/var/www`.

You are mounting your host's `/var/www` on `/usr/share/nginx/html` inside the container.

It looks like you either need to (a) modify your ngingx configuration, or (b) mount your hosts's `/var/www` inside the container as `/var/www`, or (c) you have some of your `-v` specifications backwards (the syntax is `-v <host_path>:<container_path>`)

Comment: You were right, `-v /var/www:/var/www` fixed my issue.